# How do I set LaTeX to use a different font when a font has no italics built in?

Tags: fonts

I'm using Helvetica Neue Light as the default in my document (working off a template), but when I specify /emph, it simply gives me a warning in

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'EU2/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/it' undefined
>
> Using 'EU2/HelveticaNeueLight(0)/m/n instead on input line

and the output is simply normal, un-italicized text.

The style sheet looks as follows:

```
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Helvetica Neue}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Helvetica Neue UltraLight}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Helvetica Neue Light}
```

Any idea how I get around this? I do have the Helvetica Neue Light Italic font installed on my system, if that helps.

Comment: You must provide the name of the italic font to `fontspec`, like this (note the new options-after-font syntax): `\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue Light}[Mapping=tex-text, ItalicFont=Helvetica Neue Light Italic]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provide the italic font to `fontspec` with its key-value option syntax. Note the reversed order of font-then-options and the fact that TeX ligatures (`--`/`---`/curly typographers' quotes) are set up automatically in the latest version of `fontspec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Helvetica Neue Light}[
  ItalicFont=Helvetica Neue Light Italic,
]

\begin{document}
Test \emph{test}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Paul! Thanks for the reply, it seems to be exactly what I need to do. However, my document now won't compile at all. It gives me the error '! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}'

Any idea what to do there? I haven't changed anything else, just replaced the code you provided over my \setmainfont command.

Comment: @Martin You probably have an older version of `fontspec`; please, update your TeX system. In the meantime you can use `\setmainfont[<options>]{<font>}` instead of `\setmainfont{<font>}[<options>]` like in Paul's answer.

Comment: `Mapping=tex-text` should be either left out (newer versions of `fontspec` apply it automatically) or called `Ligatures=TeX`.

Comment: @egreg thanks so much, that fixed it for me! It's weird though, I checked my MikTeX packages, and according to it, fontspec is up-to-date (it is an old package, from 2013, but it seems to be the newest one in the repos I checked)

Comment: Is there any way to do this only in a selected part of the document? My specific problem is that I use the libertine circled numbers extensively, but these only exist in the main font. So when I am in italics I have to set normal font for each and every number.

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn just make a command for the circled numbers that switches the font and places the number. In any event, this is not related to the OP's question—if you can't figure it out, please ask a new question of your own.